# Достать из базы суммы за 30 дней из 3 таблиц по дате

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Есть такое, дело:

Нужно отобразить на графике прибыль за 30 дней с 3 таблиц одновременно, каждая таблица отвечает за свой продукт, т.е в итогде из базы я должен получить следующий массив `array('date' => $date, 'table_x_sum => $sumX, 'table_y_sum' => $sumY, 'table_z_sum' => $sumZ);`

Если брать с одной таблицы, то получается следующий запрос:

```
'SELECT DATE(date) as DATE, SUM(replace(`summa`, ",", ".")) shopSum
                FROM shop_order
                GROUP BY  DATE(date) DESC
                LIMIT 0, 30'
```

Как мне сделать `JOIN`, еще 2-ух таблиц по дате?

Comment: Вы гарантируете, что в таблице НЕТ ПРОПУСКОВ по дате?

Comment: Нет, вполне возможно, что в некоторые дни покупок не было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT q0.date
     , COALESCE(q1.shopSum, 0) shopSum1
     , COALESCE(q2.shopSum, 0) shopSum2
     , COALESCE(q3.shopSum, 0) shopSum3
FROM
(
  SELECT DATE(date) date FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT DATE(date) FROM table2
  UNION
  SELECT DATE(date) FROM table3
) q0
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DATE(date) date
       , SUM(replace(`summa`, ",", ".")) shopSum
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
) q1 ON q0.date = q1.date
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DATE(date) date
       , SUM(replace(`summa`, ",", ".")) shopSum
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
) q2 ON q0.date = q2.date
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DATE(date) date
       , SUM(replace(`summa`, ",", ".")) shopSum
  FROM table3
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
) q3 ON q0.date = q3.date
ORDER BY q0.date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Если же отсутствие "пропусков" в датах гарантировано, можно упростить до

```
SELECT q1.date
     , q1.shopSum shopSum1
     , q2.shopSum shopSum2
     , q3.shopSum shopSum3
FROM
(
  SELECT DATE(date) date
       , SUM(replace(`summa`, ",", ".")) shopSum
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
) q1 
JOIN
(
  SELECT DATE(date) date
       , SUM(replace(`summa`, ",", ".")) shopSum
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
) q2 ON q1.date = q2.date
JOIN
(
  SELECT DATE(date) date
       , SUM(replace(`summa`, ",", ".")) shopSum
  FROM table3
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
) q3 ON q1.date = q3.date
ORDER BY q1.date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Если возможно, что за какую-то дату во всех трёх магазинах покупок не было, но данные на эту дату, пусть и нулевые, нужны - потребуется опорная таблица дат (возможно, динамически генерируемая). Типа:

```
(
    SELECT DATEADD('d', -q02.delta, MAX(q01.date)) date
    FROM
    (
      SELECT MAX(DATE(date)) date FROM table1
      UNION
      SELECT MAX(DATE(date)) FROM table2
      UNION
      SELECT MAX(DATE(date)) FROM table3
    ) q01,
    (
    SELECT xx.x*6+yy.y delta
    FROM (SELECT 0 x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xx,
         (SELECT 0 y UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) yy
    ) q02
)q0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сам бы точно бы не справился!

Comment: В первом случае, отдельно выбирать даты и потом по ним, вторым проходом, клеить результаты немного избыточно. Думаю проще что нибудь вроде https://pastebin.com/Q0T1NWkT  при желании, если вдруг оптимизатору будет проще, можно части union сгруппировать каждый до даты сам по себе и потом еще раз сгруппировать все вместе